# How to send logged email using smtp in c#?

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I wanted to know how I can send a logged email (visible in sent items) via smtp in c#.

Model I'm using :

```
try  
{  
    SmtpClient mailServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);  
    mailServer.EnableSsl = true;  
mailServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword");  
string from = "myemail@gmail.com";  
    string to = "reciever@gmail.com";  
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);  
    msg.Subject = "Enter the subject here";  
    msg.Body = "The message goes here.";
    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("D:\\myfile.txt"));
    mailServer.Send(msg);  
}  
catch (Exception ex)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to send email. Error : " + ex);  
}
```

But i can't see it in sent mails.

Comment: Have tried to log out and log in again with the client you are using to check and still don't see it?

Comment: @Fildor Yes I did try that.

Comment: Did you see in spam?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty checked it. Not found

Comment: Do you check exactly THAT account?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy yeah ofc

Comment: Try to add Message-Id. Some details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874964/why-emails-sent-by-net-smtpclient-are-missing-message-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

The only way to add the message to your Sent folder is to specifically add it there yourself using the IMAP protocol (or via a library that implements the IMAP protocol).

Comment: Could you recommend such library?